# Want to take all Januarys from 2000 to 2021

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD09GA")

var iniDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2000,1,1)
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2021,12,30)
var mon = collection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 1, 'month'));
```

//will it work?

Comment: Have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You could just see for yourself, if you get the expected imagery. Yes, this works.

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD09GA")

var iniDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2000,1,1)
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2021,12,30)
var mon = collection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 1, 'month'));
print(mon.aggregate_array('system:time_start').map(function (t) {
  return ee.Date(t)
}))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1ecbed645b96069eef5cafb2b6c38e52